# iOS App change universal to iPhone only

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, appcelerator

We have a app that was submitted as a universal app with support for all devices iPad and iPhone but we no longer want it to show in the store as a iPad app we want it to just be a iPhone only app.

This app was built with Appcelerator so i have changed the app tiapp.xml details to only support iPhone no longer universal, but it will not submitted to the store.

I can't upload the existing app because the family group in the bundle Id. it won't accept removing the iPad.

How can we remove the app from being listed as a iPad app really important as the app was not built with iPad in mind it would be fine if it was just a scaled up version of the app.

Any help please?

Comment: To my knowledge you can't remove iPad support from an app which had previously had iPad support. You will have to submit your onder a different name.

Comment: check details by apple for this problem  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1623/_index.html

Comment: I think you should be able to upload iphone only app by increasing version number of app in tiapp.xml

Comment: you can't downgrade your app from _universal_ to _iPhone-only_.

Answer (score 1):

> Developers who wish to issue updates, but remove device support, have
>   three choices:
>
> Fix their app so that it can work on the devices they originally set
>   out to support. Target a newer version of iOS that requires a newer
>   device. Remove their app from the store, and upload the new app with a
>   different bundle ID.

Comment: Can someone please explain this Target a newer version of iOS that requires a newer device. This seems like the only one we cannot pull it.

Comment: Targeting the Latest iOS

An update to an app can always require a newer version of iOS. This will drop support for devices that cannot run that version of iOS.

The "iOS Deployment Target" build setting is the minimum version of iOS your app supports. Your app cannot be installed or run on any device that cannot run that version of iOS.

Comment: It basically means that you need to wait until the device you want to stop supporting doesn't receive the new iOS version, and then you set your apps deployment target this iOS version therefore cutting of these devices.

Comment: Ok thanks for the information all, unfortunately this wont work either. The old thing that may work is if i could force the app to show in compatibility mode for iPad is this possible? cant find any info if this is even possible with Appcelerator. Thanks

Comment: if i add UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities to need to telephony will this stop it showing for ipad? as it doesnt support it https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html

Comment: No, once an app has been released on the App Store as Universal it cannot be changed to be iPhone only (this is how you get "compatibility mode"). Your only options are to continue iPad support or delete the existing app from the store and release a new app with a new name.

Comment: It will show for iPad also but user will not download it if you put some device capabilities in .plist file.

Comment: Did you see the note in the document you linked to?  You can only expand the compatible devices via UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities. You cannot be more restrictive

Comment: @Paulw11, If developer upload the universal app initially, and in next update developer select the iPhone under build(general)settings, then app must support iphone only. But it is not the case(I am facing the same issue). If apple does not allow to change the supported devices later on, then this option must be at iTunesConnect while creating the app. What is the use of device settings in xcode? What is your opinion.

Comment: The first time you upload an app, iTunes determines whether it is iPhone only, iPad only or universal. If it is universal then it will always be universal and you cannot make it more restrictive with an update. If it is iPhone only or iPad only then you can make it universal with an update but then you can never go back or iPhone only or iPad only. You also cannot change from iPad only to iPhone only or vice-versa.