# Is it possible to change the universal app to iphone only once it is uploaded to app store?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store-connect

I am trying to upload new version of my app which is only compatible for iphone. Earlier it was uploaded as universal app. Is it Possible to disable the 
IPAD compatibility during the next upload to the App store?

Anyone have idea about this ?

Comment: yes, but you have to re-upload new version to app store

Comment: How? By changing the targeted Device to iphone only?@UmairAfzal

Comment: yes. General Settings-> Deployment Info -> Devices -> iPhone

Comment: Thanks for reply @UmairAfzal. will it remove iPad compatibility from app store?

Comment: @UmairAfzal did this work for you, by changing the targeted Device? My app is already in the store for both iPhone and iPad but for the latest release, I don't want it to be available for iPad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities** would help you.

Put **telephony** value like this in info.plist (IPhone specific...)

Of course you need submit your app again.

[UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html)

> UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities
>
> UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities (Array or Dictionary - iOS) lets iTunes and the App Store know which device-related features an app requires in order to run. **iTunes and the mobile App Store use this list to prevent customers from installing apps on a device that does not support the listed capabilities.**

[image]

Comment: It will remove iPad compatibility from app store? @HwanghoKim

Comment: It will prevent customers from installing apps on a device. I updated my answer. Please have a look.

Comment: what if i follow the way suggested by Lal Krishna. Which is better?  Thanks for the help @HwanghoKim.

Comment: In my case already uploaded app is universal app its supporting iphone and ipad. Now i want to change ipad only it is possible ?

Comment: in my project there were written "arm7" no telephony

Answer (score 6):

Hopefully this will help.

[iOS App change universal to iPhone only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37586843/ios-app-change-universal-to-iphone-only)

> Developers who wish to issue updates, but remove device support, have three choices:
>
> Fix their app so that it can work on the devices they originally set
>   out to support. Target a newer version of iOS that requires a newer
>   device. Remove their app from the store, and upload the new app with a
>   different bundle ID.

[Switch universal app to iPhone only app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35055402/switch-universal-app-to-iphone-only-app)

1. Remove this App from app store
2. Create new bundle & use it to your new app version
3. Deploy App to the store

For more ideas visit the link above.

Comment: I'm not a fan of [link only answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers).  It'd be nice if you would provide an actual answer beyond a simple "look at these links".