# Change app from universal to iPhone-only in App Store?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I uploaded the build to the App Store with UIRequiredDeviceCapability: "telephony", to make sure it's only for iPhone. The target device family in Build Settings is also 1 (iPhone-only).

However before submitting the App to review, Ipad pictures are still needed.. How do I change this?

Comment: FYI - you are not allowed to change a universal app to iPhone-only. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37586843/ios-app-change-universal-to-iphone-only

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS App change universal to iPhone only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37586843/ios-app-change-universal-to-iphone-only)